# My applet runs in the IDE but not in the Browser.

Tags: java, applet

My applet will run in the IDE but not in the browser.  It will open but does not seem to read in the html files into the jEditorPane1 when the "Next" button is clicked.  In fact when the "Next" button is clicked, nothing happens, but runs fine in the IDE. 
this is the method code:

```
    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        if(fileNumber > 4){
            fileNumber = 0;
        }

        java.net.URL helpURL = NewJFrame.class.getResource(
                                fileNumbers.get(fileNumber));
        if (helpURL != null) {
    try {
        jEditorPane1.setPage(helpURL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + helpURL);
    }
} else {
    System.err.println("Couldn't find file: file.html");
}
            fileNumber++;
    }                                     

    private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        if(problemNumber>3){
            problemNumber = 0;
        }
        fileNumbers = problems.get(problemNumber);
        fileNumber =0;
        java.net.URL helpURL = NewJFrame.class.getResource(
                                fileNumbers.get(fileNumber));
        if (helpURL != null) {
    try {
        jEditorPane1.setPage(helpURL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + helpURL);
    }
} else {
    System.err.println("Couldn't find file: file.html");
}
            fileNumber++;
        problemNumber++;
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: BTW - `jButton2MouseClicked` Don't add a mouse listener to buttons.  They already accept a better listener - an `ActionListener`..

Comment: Thank you Andrew.  I read the SSCE and used the HTML validator and found my html files have errors.  I used Kompozer to write them.  I will write them manually.  I am a teacher and this is for my students.  Your expertise and help will be much appreiciated..

Comment: *"I am a teacher and this is for my students."*  Please don't waste the time of your students on applets.  From my 'copy/paste comments'..  Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). - I fully endorse that advice (no surprise, since the blog article was written by me).  To add to that, applets have become irrelevant, there is very little an applet can do that can't be done with HTML/JS, further..

Comment: .. further all applets these days need to be digitally signed (with a certificate that costs quite a lot, typically) & both IE and Chrome browsers are set to drop support for applets completely, while both FF and Safari put extra dialogs between the user and a running applet.